# How to make the pdf height and width same as html while converting html to pdf using html2pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, html2pdf

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiCPg.png)

How to remove the extra space in the pdf? I'm using html2pdf.

can anyone please help?

Below is my sample code

```
var $Obj = $("<div/>").html('<div style="height: 300; width: 400; border: 3px solid #ccc; min-height:500px"><p style="margin-top:20px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p> <p  style="margin-top:20px">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>');
       
html2pdf($Obj[0], {
    margin: 0,
    filename: 'sample.pdf',
    html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
    jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
});
```

Comment: Please add more information. Show some code that explains what you tried. Add reference to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link given below and set height accordingly to A4 size

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', array($width_in_mm,$height_in_mm), 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Width and Height should be in MM.

```
$width_in_mm = $width_in_inches * 25.4; 
$height_in_mm = $height_in_inches * 25.4;
```

[HTML2PDF page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467783/html2pdf-page-size)